# expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token Vector

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following compilation error:

expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token Vector

```
const std::vector<double>* t_vector = &my->thresholds;

if(t_vector.size >= 10)
{
  std::cout << t_vector->[i];
}
```

The error is at the std::cout statement

I've also tried the following:

```
std::cout << t_vector[i]
std::cout << *t_vector[i]
```

Comment: @cbel Neither less worse: `threshold_vector->[i];` The OP should get a book about c++ basics, but certainly not ask here!

Comment: -1 because these are really trivial mistakes and you should learn from [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before resorting to asking here.

Answer (score 1):

This `threshold_vector->[i]` syntax simply does not exist.

You meant to dereference `threshold_vector`:

`*threshold_vector`

then invoke the `[]` operator on the result; to do so, you need to use a parenthesis:

`(*threshold_vector)[i]`

The `->` syntax only works for function calls (be they of the form `obj->foo()` or `obj->operator[](i)`!), not the infix/prefix/postfix operators, due to various complexities of the language's grammar.

Similarly, write `threshold_vector->size()` not `threshold_vector.size`.

Also, hopefully, you meant `std::vector<double>` and not `std::double<vector>`?!

Comment: Nitpick: "The -> syntax only works for non-operator function calls" - `threshold_vector->operator[](i)` should work too :o)

Answer (score 0):

beside mistakes that mentioned above you must note that since `threshold_vector` is declared as a pointer you may face problem compiling `if(threshold_vector.size >= 10)`.

use `threshold_vector->size` instead. again im not sure that vector template has a field called size. it is a property i guess.

Comment: The C++ terminology is "member variable"/"data member" not "field", and "member function" not "property".

Comment: `after delcaring this pointer you have assigned it to a reference of an object` What do you mean?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for the note about terminology, im involved in a c# project recently, couses this kind of mistakes :D